# Is there a way to trim a TM_FILENAME beyond using TM_FILENAME_BASE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet for a redux container file that takes an import of some react file of the same base name. TM_FILENAME_BASE works great for removing the .js from the file name but in this case, my component file's extension is fun-thing.component.js and the container will follow suit with an extension that is fun-thing.container.js.

The Regex I am using to select everything before the first period is `^([^.]+)`

```
  "Redux Container": {
    "prefix": "rc",
    "body": [
      "// @flow",
      "import { connect } from 'react-redux';",
      "import { ${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)/${1:/pascalcase}/}Component } from './${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)/$1/}.component';",
      "",
      "const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});",
      "",
      "const mapDispatchToProps = {};",
      "",
      "export const ${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)/${1:/pascalcase}/} = connect(",
      "  mapStateToProps,",
      "  mapDispatchToProps",
      ")(${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)/${1:/pascalcase}/}Component);"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a normal container for a normal component"
  }
```

expected

```
// @flow
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FunThingComponent } from './fun-thing.component';
...
```

actual

```
// @flow
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FunThing.container.jsComponent } from './FunThing.container.js.component';
...
```

As you can see, it is not omitting the file extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these work:

```
  "import { ${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+).*/${1:/pascalcase}/}Component } from './${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+).*/$1/}.component';",

  "import { ${TM_FILENAME/(.*?)\\..+/${1:/pascalcase}/}Component } from './${TM_FILENAME/(.*?)\\..+/$1/}.component';"
```

With the vscode snippet transforms if you want to **exclude** part of the variable as you want, removing the `.component.js` from the filename, then that part of the variable must be accounted for in the regex - hence  `(.*?)\\..+`.

Otherwise that "unseen" part of the variable just passes through.

So your regex `^([^.]+)` was accurately capturing the part of the filename before the first `.` but then the rest of the variable was "passing through" unmodified.

You can see this more clearly with this example:

```
"import { ${TM_FILENAME//${1:/pascalcase}/}Component }
```

that yields:

```
import { fun-thing.component.jsComponent }
```

so the entire filename is passed through although none of it is captured.

```
${someVariable/everything To Be Transformed/what To Do To the previous/}
```

if it isn't in the "everything to be transformed" part nothing happens to it.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented that first one and it did the trick. What you said about the unseen part makes complete sense.